# MySQL Query IN() Clause Slow on Indexed Column

Tags: php, mysql, performance

I Have a MySQL query that is being generated by a PHP script, the query will look something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Recipe_Data WHERE 404_Without_200 = 0 AND Failures_Without_Success = 0 AND RHD_No IN (10, 24, 34, 41, 43, 51, 57, 59, 61, 67, 84, 90, 272, 324, 402, 405, 414, 498, 500, 501, 510, 559, 562, 595, 632, 634, 640, 643, 647, 651, 703, 714, 719, 762, 765, 776, 796, 812, 814, 815, 822, 848, 853, 855, 858, 866, 891, 920, 947, 956, 962, 968, 1049, 1054, 1064, 1065, 1070, 1100, 1113, 1119, 1130, 1262, 1287, 1292, 1313, 1320, 1327, 1332, 1333, 1335, 1340, 1343, 1344, 1346, 1349, 1352, 1358, 1362, 1365, 1482, 1495, 1532, 1533, 1537, 1549, 1550, 1569, 1571, 1573, 1574, 1596, 1628, 1691, 1714, 1720, 1735, 1755, 1759, 1829, 1837, 1844, 1881, 1919, 2005, 2022, 2034, 2035, 2039, 2054, 2076, 2079, 2087, 2088, 2089, 2090, 2091, 2092, 2154, 2155, 2156, 2157, 2160, 2162, 2164, 2166, 2169, 2171, 2174, 2176, 2178, 2179, 2183, 2185, 2186, 2187, 2201, 2234, 2236, 2244, 2245, 2250, 2255, 2260, 2272, 2280, 2281, 2282, 2291, 2329, 2357, 2375, 2444, 2451, 2452, 2453, 2454, 2456, 2457, 2460, 2462, 2464, 2465, 2467, 2468, 2469, 2470, 2473, 2474, 2481, 2485, 2487, 2510, 2516, 2519, 2525, 2540, 2545, 2547, 2553, 2571, 2579, 2580, 2587, 2589, 2597, 2602, 2611, 2629, 2660, 2662, 2700, 2756, 2825, 2833, 2835, 2858, 2958, 2963, 2964, 3009, 3090, 3117, 3118, 3120, 3121, 3122, 3123, 3126, 3127, 3129, 3130, 3133, 3135, 3137, 3138, 3139, 3141, 3142, 3145, 3146, 3147, 3151, 3152, 3155, 3193, 3201, 3204, 3219, 3221, 3222, 3223, 3224, 3225, 3226, 3227, 3228, 3229, 3231, 3232, 3233, 3234, 3235, 3237, 3239, 3246, 3250, 3253, 3259, 3261, 3291, 3315, 3328, 3377, 3381, 3383, 3384, 3385, 3387, 3388, 3389, 3390, 3396, 3436, 3463, 3465, 3467, 3470, 3471, 3484, 3507, 3515, 3554, 3572, 3641, 3672, 3683, 3689, 3690, 3692, 3693, 3694, 3697, 3698, 3705, 3711, 3713, 3715, 3716, 3717, 3719, 3720, 3722, 3726, 3727, 3732, 3737, 3763, 3767, 3770, 3771, 3772, 3773, 3803, 3810, 3812, 3816, 3846, 3847, 3848, 3851, 3874, 3882, 3902, 3903, 3906, 3908, 3916, 3924, 3967, 3987, 4006, 4030, 4043, 4045, 4047, 4058, 4067, 4107, 4108, 4114, 4115, 4131, 4132, 4133, 4137, 4138, 4139, 4140, 4141, 4142, 4146, 4150, 4151, 4152, 4153, 4157, 4158, 4160, 4163, 4166, 4167, 4171, 4179, 4183, 4221, 4225, 4242, 4257, 4435, 4437, 4438, 4443, 4446, 4449, 4450, 4451, 4452, 4454, 4460, 4550, 4557, 4618, 4731, 4775, 4804, 4972, 5025, 5026, 5039, 5042, 5294, 5578, 5580, 5599, 5602, 5649, 5726, 5779, 5783, 5931, 5934, 5936, 5939, 5940, 5941, 5978, 6044, 6056, 6113, 6116, 6118, 6122, 6123, 6125, 6127, 6128, 6129, 6130, 6131, 6135, 6141, 6145, 6147, 6150, 6152, 6153, 6154, 6160, 6166, 6169);
```

The column RHD_No is the primary key for this database, and there are about 400,000 rows total. The problem is, the query is extremely slow, it's often around 2 seconds, but I've seen it get as long as 10.

When I try to explain the query, everything seems like it should be fine:

```
+----+-------------+-------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table       | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | Recipe_Data | range | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL |  420 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
```

When I profile the query I get:

```
mysql> show profile;
+--------------------------------+----------+
| Status                         | Duration |
+--------------------------------+----------+
| starting                       | 0.000015 |
| checking query cache for query | 0.000266 |
| Opening tables                 | 0.000009 |
| System lock                    | 0.000004 |
| Table lock                     | 0.000006 |
| init                           | 0.000115 |
| optimizing                     | 0.000038 |
| statistics                     | 0.000797 |
| preparing                      | 0.000047 |
| executing                      | 0.000002 |
| Sending data                   | 2.675270 |
| end                            | 0.000007 |
| query end                      | 0.000003 |
| freeing items                  | 0.000071 |
| logging slow query             | 0.000002 |
| logging slow query             | 0.000058 |
| cleaning up                    | 0.000005 |
+--------------------------------+----------+
```

I've been working on this problem for a long time and I haven't been able to find a solution. Is there anything overtly wrong with this query? I don't see how looking at 420 rows should take 2+ seconds.

Comment: Just a hunch, but what do all your indexes look like on `Recipe_Data`?

Comment: I have a primary key an RHD_No, and a UNIQUE key on another column.

Comment: Not keys (per se), but indexes.  I'm not a mysql expert, so this isn't an answer, but have you tried adding an index on `404_Without_200, Failures_Without_Success`?  See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html for usage in queries, and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html for creating indexes.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You are accessing 420 rows by primary key which will probably lead to an index access path. This could access 2 index pages and one data page per key. If these are in cache, the query should run fast. If not, every page access that goes to disk will incur the usual disk latency. If we assume 5ms disk latency and 80% cache hits, we arrive at 420*3*0.2*5ms=1.2 seconds which is on the order of what you're seeing.

Comment: So how would I go about improving my query?

Answer (score 14):

The problem is that `IN` is basically treated as a bunch of `OR`s (e.g.

```
col IN (1,2,3)
```

is

```
col = 1 OR col = 2 OR col = 3
```

This is a LOT slower than a join.

What you should do is to generate the SQL code which creates the temporary table, populates it with the values in the "IN" clause, and then join with that temp table

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE numbers (n INT)
```

Then in a loop, add

```
INSERT numbers  VALUES ($next_number)
```

Then at the end

```
SELECT * FROM numbers, Recipe_Data 
WHERE numbers.n = RHD_No
```

Comment: Don't forget to drop the temp table at the end, obviously :)

Comment: I think that the performance of `IN` clauses like that must vary a lot from server to server. This question is tagged "mysql" so maybe that's what you're referring to.  In my experience with SQL Server 2000/2005, large `IN` clauses for primary key lookups were extremely fast (the database and queries in the application I'm thinking of were all pretty highly optimized; it was all code in a high-traffic, large-volume web app).

Comment: @Pointy - It may be server specific, I know that Sybase had that performance behavior with IN, at least on older versions (pre 12).

Comment: I've also seen performance issues with large `IN` clauses.  MySQL doesn't seem to using the indexes as well it could be with these clauses.

Comment: is there any function for multiple AND function like OR (IN function)?

Answer (score 10):

You should transform the IN clauses to INNER JOIN clauses.

You can transform a query like this one:

```
SELECT  foo   
FROM    bar   
WHERE bar.stuff IN  
       (SELECT  stuff FROM asdf)
```

Into a query like this other one:

```
SELECT  b.foo 
FROM    ( 
        SELECT  DISTINCT stuff 
        FROM    asdf ) a 
JOIN    bar b 
ON      b.stuff = a.stuff
```

You will gain a lot of performance.

As the php generate the query, try some kind of trick like a temporary table for the items inside the IN clause. Always try to avoid the IN clauses if you can, because they are very time consuming.

Comment: Could you perhaps provide a link that explains why and/or measures how much in clauses are slower than joins?

Comment: Of course: http://explainextended.com/2009/08/18/passing-parameters-in-mysql-in-list-vs-temporary-table/

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to gamble here and suggest that executing the following query just once to create an index suitable for your query should reduce the query time by at least a second...

```
CREATE INDEX returnstatus ON Recipe_Data(404_Without_200,Failures_Without_Success)
```

See:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html for creating indexes, and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html for how indexes are used in queries.

Failing that, view all running processes on mysql to see if a currently running query from any source just refuses to die while consuming all the server's time and kill it.  See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/kill.html

Failing that, determine what else each record may have in common to avoid having to reference each one individually by ID number in your `IN` statement.  If necessary, add another table column to track that commonality.  Then, add column(s) having that commonality to the above index and filter by that in your `WHERE` clause instead of using the `IN` statement.  For example, if you want only those ID numbers to print out on page, have a `visible` column as type: `tinyint` with value `0` to exclude, and value `1` to include in your search results, then add `visible` column to your indexs *and* `WHERE` clause to speed up the query.  You wouldn't need that `IN` statement at all.

Perhaps your `in` statement is dynamically built using a previous query.  If that's the case, try pulling all rows with `Recipe_Data WHERE 404_Without_200 = 0 AND Failures_Without_Success = 0`.  Then in your PHP script, simply discard a record in your fetch loop if the `RHD_No` doesn't match an expected value.

Answer (score 0):

For someone like me using SQlAlchemy, using for-loop is also a good option:

```
rows=[]

for id in ids:
  row = cls.query.filter(cls.id==id).first()
  if row:
     rows.append(row)

#return rows
```