# Is this an inefficient query in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, indexing

```
mysql> desc posts_posts;
+------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id    | int(11)    | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| body       | text       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at | datetime   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at | datetime   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| is_deleted | tinyint(1) | NO   |     | 0       |                |
+------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
6 rows in set (0.06 sec)

mysql> desc posts_personas_assc;
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| post_id    | int(11)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| persona_id | int(11)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Basically, user creates posts. Each post can have "personas" attached to them. In other words, it's a many-to-many relationship. (There's another persona table which is not shown here)

Suppose I have *50 million documents* or so.  I want to run this query:

```
SELECT pp.id FROM posts_posts pp 
 INNER JOIN posts_persona_assc ppa ON pp.id = ppa.post_id
 WHERE ppa.persona_id IN(id1, id2, id3)
   AND start_time > pp.created_at
 ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT num;
```

- I'll have ppa.persona_id and pp.created_at indexed, of course
- the "IN" portion will never have more than 3 IDS.

**Will it be efficient enough for me to run this query? Will it be fast enough?**

This query wil be ran every time someone hits a user profile page.

Comment: Have you run any benchmarks? There are things you're not taking into account like network latency, and the raw processing power and I/O bandwidth of the database server itself.

Comment: Would probably depend on what indexes are present on the tables involved.

Comment: check the execution plan of the query

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to IN clause might give you faster result, check out IN variation at [IN Slowness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4771035/mysql-query-in-clause-slow-on-indexed-column)