# Combining two MySQL queries into one

Tags: mysql, sql, select, left-join, in-operator

In my database, I have two tables: Replies and Threads.

I'm trying to make a Contributions page showing what threads users have started or replied to.

Inside Replies are "ThreadId" and "Poster" which specify the Id of the thread it was replied to, and each row in Threads has an Id column as well as a "Poster" column.

I'm trying to make a query to get the rows of all THREADS in which a user has either posted or posted in.

Example:

```
$myUsername = "Bob";
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `Threads` WHERE `Poster`='$myUsername'
OR (another query to find if they had a row in Replies matching `ThreadId`='$tid'
AND `Poster`='$myUsername')");
```

Thanks

Comment: Post SHOW CREATE TABLE Threads and SHOW CREATE TABLE Replies

Comment: Left Join Poster with Threads.

Comment: post your structure on http://sqlfiddle.com/ and we will be glad to answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use an IN clause to specify that the thread id should be in those returned by a query in the replies table. Something like this is I understand correctly the structure of your tables.

```
SELECT * FROM Threads WHERE Poster = $myUsername OR Id IN (
SELECT ThreadId FROM Replies WHERE Poster = $myUsername
)
```

Comment: This query takes a very long time to load and uses a large amount of CPU. I have over 10,000 rows in Threads and 100,000 rows in Replies. Is it the query or my db?

Comment: Do you have the necessary indexes in place in order for the query to run faster? Can you see which parts of the query take the longest to execute?

Comment: I do not know how to see which parts take the longest to execute, but I tried replacing "SELECT * FROM" to simply "SELECT `Id` FROM" which is the index of the rows, and it still loaded slowly.

Comment: Are you using some graphical tool to access your DB (ex. MySQL Wrokbench)? You should be able to use your tool to "explain" the query and see exactly which steps MySQL goes through to execute it. Indexes don't have to do with the SELECT part of your query but with the WHERE part so it shouldn't make much difference whether you select the whole record or just the id assuming your records aren't really huge.

Comment: I use phpMyAdmin, but I wouldn't know how to do that. :/

Comment: I ran both of the queries separately but both loaded instantly... however, when combining them in the query you provided, it never loads and brings MySQL to an 89% CPU usage.

Comment: I think there are already some other questions in stackoverflow on optimising your queries in MySQLm for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/586381/mysql-not-using-indexes-with-where-in-clause or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4771035/mysql-query-in-clause-slow-on-indexed-column Perhaps you can get more information from there.

Answer (score 0):

Using Christina's solution probably won't result in a very efficient query. The following *should* be better:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Threads t1
WHERE t1.Poster='$myUsername'
UNION
SELECT *
FROM Threads t2
INNER JOIN replies r
ON t2.id=r.thread_id
WHERE t2.Poster<>'$myUsername'
AND r.Poster='$myUsername';
```

However:

1) do you really need all the columns from the threas table? Even if you do, using '*' is messy

2) you are still going to get duplicates if the user made more more than one reply - but this can't be fixed while you are using '*'

3) the query will still be slow eith large amounts of data if you don't have an index on poster in both tables.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this differently.
The two queries provided returned duplicates and what not, so I've decided to go a little longer way.

What I did:

1) Go through each of the user's replies, and get the thread id

2) Build a query string using these IDs, e.g. "OR Id=$threadId OR Id=$threadId2" etc

3) Put the query string into a thread query such as SELECT * FROM Threads WHERE Poster=$user $queryString2

4) Solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

You can use **LEFT OUTER JOIN** instead of **IN** operator

```
SELECT T.* 
FROM Threads T 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Replies R ON T.Id = R.ThreadId AND R.Poster = $myUsername
WHERE T.Poster = $myUsername OR R.Id IS NOT NULL
```