# Magento lost connection to mysql server during query on deletion of 50000 products

Tags: mysql, magento, nginx, magento-1.7, database-performance

I am deleting 50000 products from Magento using MySql query but every time I am getting timeout error.

```
 lost connection to mysql server during query
```

Is there any way to fix this? I have already increased the `max_execution_time` in the php.ini.

I have also set `max_allowed_packet` to *64M*

I am using following command to delete the products.

**DELETE FROM catalog_product_entity WHERE entity_id IN (here I am providing the entity_ids with comma separated)**

```
DELETE FROM catalog_product_entity WHERE entity_id IN ('1','2','3',.......'5000')
```

Is there any other way of deleting the products safely without time out?

**Note :** will this command help me speed up the application

```
mysql -u root -pYOURPASSWORD -e "flush query cache";
```

I have set this to run after every 9 minutes using cronjob

My database size is very huge, more than 50GB and server is dedicated server with 16 GB RAM.

I am running this query directly in phpmyadmin.

Entities are in random order

Comment: Is the entity_id in consecutive order? Can you do some think like `where entity_id NOT IN (1,3) and entity_id <= 5000`

Comment: No entity in not in consecutive order

Comment: Take a look @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4771035/mysql-query-in-clause-slow-on-indexed-column

Answer (score 1):

A couple thoughts depending on your situation:

1. Are you using a persistent DB connection? Are tables being used/locked during your query?
   Look at `mysql_pconnect` [mysql_pconnect — Open a persistent connection to a MySQL server](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-pconnect.php)
2. Maybe you just need to adjust the default timeout for MySQL?
   Look here on **[How to Change the MySQL Timeout on a Server](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/how-to-change-the-mysql-timeout-on-a-server)**
3. There is also a good answer here which may be your issue since it's such a large query:
   [Lost connection to MySQL server during query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884859/lost-connection-to-mysql-server-during-query)

Comment: I am running this query directly in phpmyadmin.

Comment: Then option #2 or #3 may apply. READ the information at those links!